# How to increase size of Inspector in IE to search more deep DOM structure

Tags: selenium, internet-explorer

How can i increase IE Element inspector capacity to show more deep html elements on Spy.
My Web page is Having long deep DOM structure.

Comment: Hi, you can use the Console tab of the f12 tool to list elements by selector. eg. console.dir(document.querySelectorAll('body *')) will list the child elements of the body....

Comment: i cannot see any option to try that in Console tab. i have copied each child elements of HTML and pasted in wordpad. i have repeated the same thing for inside iframes!

Comment: you can execute code from the console... you should ask your teacher or a friend to explain how to use the dev tool. If you have a large DOM tree. use querySelectorAll to list only those elements in the DOM tree that you are interested in. eg. document.querySelectorAll('body > div') will list the first div element that is a child of the body.